# split time java (gui) and display

Tags: java, netbeans

### Sample code:

```
sx = new String(""+hours+"           "+min+ "         "+sec+"."+b.format(mil));
lbl.setText(sx);
```

Then when I make method:

```
public void split(){
String[] r= s.split(" ");
System.out.println(r);
{
button private void sp1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  usedwatch1.split();        
}
```

But it gave me wrong answer. I want to get the split time when I click to the button split.

Comment: try using `Arrays.toString(r)` instead of just `r`

Comment: Thank you :) I tried what you said it gave a right answer but [0, , , , , , , , , , , 0, , , , , , , , , 0.44] how to remove ........

Comment: thank you I did it already I replace my code to your suggested code then I add (:)   public void split(){
//   long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
//      pausedTime -= (now - watchStart);
//      myTimer1.stop();
//      
//                 paused = true;
//    jLabel10.setText(lbl.getText()); 

            String[] r= s.split(":");
            
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(r));

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
sx = new String(""+hours+";"+min+ ";"+sec+"."+b.format(mil));
String s[]=sx.split(";");
for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++) 
    System.out.println(s[i]);
```